# How to count Tabular

Tags: latex, pdflatex

for some reason i need to make many tables with latex, and non of them should have caption nor labels, but they need to be numbered like Subsection.tableNo. I have tried to use

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}  
...& ... & No.: \arabic{subsection}.\arabic{table}\\\hline
.....
\end{tabular}
```

however, because i'm using only tabular environment, the table counter will not be set, so i always get like this:

```
... ... 1.0

... ... 1.0

... ... 2.0

... ... 2.0
```

how can i get the tabular counted? thx

(and..sry for my poor english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to tap into the beginning of an environment `<env>` using `\AtBeginEnvironment{<env>}{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\refstepcounter{table}}

\newcommand{\showtabular}{% Just for this example
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    \thesection.\thetable \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\showtabular
\showtabular

\section{Second section}
\showtabular
\showtabular
\showtabular

\section{Last section}
\showtabular
\showtabular
\showtabular
\showtabular

\end{document}
```

Above I step (actually, the step can be referenced) the `table` counter with every new `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: tyvm! Now i can make tables faster!